# How to pass parameter in api url based on selected option?

Tags: reactjs

I would like to fetch data based on selected job id. 
Job id should be selected from drop down list.
Once the job id will be selected, api url should be adjusted with the property job id.

I added the select option and fetch statement. However I cannot pass the parameter in the url.

```
const jsonify = res => res.json();

 var chart_request = new Request(
    `https://xxxx.com/prod/job-id?job_id_number=${this.state.selectVal}`, 
    {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        })
    }
); 

const dataFetch = fetch(chart_request).then(jsonify);

export default class ZYZ extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {                                          
            selectVal : "650"
        }
    }

    setSelectValue = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            selectVal: event.target.value
        });                                                                            
    }

    render() {
        return
            <React.Fragment>
                <select value={this.state.selectVal} onChange={this.setSelectValue}>
                    <option value = "650">650</option>
                    <option value = "1052">1052</option>
                </select> 
                <p>{this.state.selectVal}</p>
            </React.Fragment>
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add proper code blocks here for better understanding.

Comment: Selection done properly. Read [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html) / tutorials about data fetching in react. It can be invoked from `setState` callback.

Answer (score 0):

**You can't use your state outside your class.**

But if you insist, you can use componentDidMount & componentDidUpdate lifecycle methods on initial load and every select respectively, and pass the id as an argument to `fetchData` & `chart_request` as follow:

```
componentDidMount() {
    // calling fetch, resolving the promise, and storing the data in state
    fetchData(this.state.selectVal).then(data => this.setState({ data }));
}

componentDidUpdate() {
    // same as above
    fetchData(this.state.selectVal).then(data => this.setState({ data }));
}
```

The modifications for `chart_request` & `fetchData`:

```
const chart_request = id =>
    fetch(
        `https://xxxx.com/prod/job-id?job_id_number=${id}`
    )
        .then(response => response.json()) // instead of "jsonify" 
        .then(data => JSON.stringify(data))
        .catch(error => error);

const fetchData = id => chart_request(id);
```

I have modified the [SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/5k83xm24lx) so you can test your output.

Comment: I tried it and I received error : Cannot read property 'selectVal' of undefined             
const dataFetch = fetch(chart_request(this.state.selectVal)).then(jsonify);

Comment: You can access your state from inside the component. Hence, you should use componentDidUpdate within your class (example attached) in order to use the selected value and fetch the data.

Comment: ok, thx for your sandbox, but the fetch need to be assigned to variable datafetch. I'm using it to create chart with fusioncharts. When I try to run it with statement: componentDidUpdate(){
        datafetch = fetch(chart_request(this.state.selectVal)).then(jsonify);
    }  then I got the message that data-fetch is not defined. Chart code looks like:

Comment: I have modified the answer so it will match your structure. It should work now :) though I really recommend you to go over this blog https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-fetching-data/.